# Dotnet Isolated Azure Function w/ .Net 6 on a Linux consumption plan complaining about 6.0 AspNetCore.App Runtime not being available

Tags: azure-functions, .net-6.0

I need some help identifying why an Azure Function deployed to a Linux consumption plan is unable to start and complaining about the AspNetCore.App runtime not being available:

[Application Insights logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPzwR.png)

What I don't quite understand is why would this be referencing RC2 at all. We've isolated the problem to a package dependency (`StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.AspNetCore" Version="7.2.1"`) - if we include this, it breaks the function as deployed in Azure.

Looking at the source for that dependency, it appears that all they're doing is referencing the AspNetCore.App framework reference like so:

https://github.com/imperugo/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions/blob/master/src/aspnet/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.AspNetCore/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.AspNetCore.csproj

Note that our Azure Function is able to run .Net 5 with the same project reference (6.x version of the same lib) without any issues.

We're using the CLI to create and deploy the function like so:

Build:

```
        - task: UseDotNet@2
          inputs:
            version: $(dotNetVersion)
          displayName: Set DotNet Version $(dotNetVersion)                       

        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          inputs:
            command: 'build'
            projects: '**/xyz.Function.OurFunction.csproj'
            arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/func_api'
          displayName: 'Build Function'
```

Function app creation:

```
az functionapp create --name $(functionAppName)
   --resource-group $(rg) --consumption-plan-location $(region) 
   --functions-version 4 --os-type Linux --runtime dotnet-isolated 
   --storage-account $(funstorageAccountName) --assign-identity '[system]'
```

Deployment:

```
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            inputs:                
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: 'functionAppLinux'
              appName: '$(functionAppName)'
              package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'
              runtimeStack: 'DOTNET-ISOLATED|6.0'
              appSettings: >-
                -FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME dotnet-isolated
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I solved this epic in my particular case. 
In .csproj properties there's `<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>` and `<AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>`. 
Build pipeline uses `Pool: Azure Pipelines` and `Image: ubuntu-latest`.

First issue I had was with the *Azure Function App Deploy* release pipeline task trying to deploy the ZIP artifact. Even if this is the Microsoft recommendation this would hang indefinitely. Therefore there's a *Extract files* task before, which unzips `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/func/drop/Functions.zip` to `$(Agent.TempDirectory)/func`. `func` is the artifact source alias in my case.

Imho, the `Azure Function App Deploy` task is obsolete. 
By default, the latest runtime stack that you might pick is `DOTNET|3.1 (functionapp v3)`. 
Then, in the task logs, one notices: 
`Trying to update App Service Application settings.`  
`Data:{"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME":"dotnet","WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE":"true"}` .
That's highly unexpected since we are using the **out of process** model. 
Also, the *Startup command is empty*. 
Tried with `func azure functionapp publish $(functions-app-name) --no-bundler` and `dotnet functions.dll` to no avail.

msdocs links below: 
functional and behavioral differences running [on out-of-process compared to .NET class library functions running in-process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#differences-with-net-class-library-functions) 
.NET isolated project [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#net-isolated-project) 
Manual [version updates on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/set-runtime-version?tabs=portal#manual-version-updates-on-linux=)

Consequently, after deployment, there's a *Azure App Service Settings* task which sets `"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME":"dotnet-isolated"`.

Then the savior was [this guide](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide.md).

> [!NOTE] To be able to publish your isolated function project to either a Windows or a Linux function app in Azure, you must set a value of dotnet-isolated in the remote FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME application setting. To support zip deployment and running from the deployment package on Linux, you also need to update the linuxFxVersion site config setting to DOTNET-ISOLATED|6.0.

Deployement is reported successful, function app says `Function host is not running.`

When I run `az functionapp config show --name $(functions-app) --resource-group $(rg) --query 'linuxFxVersion' -o tsv` I get *DOTNET|3.1*.

So I do
`az functionapp config set --name $(functions-app) --resource-group $(rg) --linux-fx-version 'DOTNET-ISOLATED|5.0'` since I am targeting netcore5.
This fixed everything and became an *Azure CLI* task after deployment in the release pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

In your Function App you need to add the application settings **SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT**

In some instances, you may be unable to deploy an app to Linux Azure Functions in the **consumption plan**. If this occurs, add an application setting named **`SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT`** with a value of **`0`**.

[image]

[image]

Refer  [here](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/Azure-Functions-4.0-GA---Known-Issues#linux-consumption-app-publishing-issues)

Comment: Just tried that but it didn't really do anything.  To be clear, the Function deploys fine and attempts to start but is unable to serve any endpoints (i.e.: it does not respond to requests since it appears to constantly restart and complain about the framework not being available).

Comment: Please check the log stream in KUDU `https://<your_app_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/LogStream`
for detail information

Comment: This is an Azure Function on a Linux consumption plan - Kudu's log stream isn't available (only the appinsights based streaming logs or filesystem logs).  Either dont show more than what was already posted above unfortunately